# Android Media Player Achieva Astone A100 missing VPN

Tags: media-player, vpn

I just bought an [Astone A100](http://achsyd1.achieva.com.au/cgi-bin/estore/HMPSTONAA100.html) which is also known as an Achieva A100.  It's an Android media player with WiFi, HDMI, and an Air Mouse.

The ROM that comes with this device is based on Android 4.0.4.  However, unlike my i9000 phone's Android 4.0.4 there doesn't appear to be a VPN option in the settings menu.

Based on Google Play Store and the SystemInfo app, this ROM identifies as "SoftwinerEvb".  Google says SoftwinerEvb is a ROM for an 8" tablet.

Is the VPN option something I can just add in, like adding kernel drivers to linux, or drivers to windows, or do I have to recompile a whole ROM for this functionality?